# (Internal)CA signed certificate on WebLogic &  same CA cert(public key) on my machine. Browser still doesn't trust

Tags: security, ssl, weblogic, ssl-certificate, ca

### Created Private Key & Self signed certficate in a Key Store

keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keystore mydomain.ks -dname cn=mydomain.com -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA1withRSA

### Created Certificate Request and sent to Internal CA

keytool -certreq -alias mydomain -keystore mydomain.ks -file mydomain_project.csr

### Once Internal(Company) CA issues the certificate - which looks like something like this

e.g.
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExADALBgkqhkiG9w0BBwGggDCCAmowggHXAhAF
UbM77e50M63v1Z2A/5O5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEOBAUAMF8xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMSAw
E+cFEpf0WForA+eRP6XraWw8rTN8102zGrcJgg4P6XVS4l39+l5aCEGGbauLP5W6
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Copied this to a .pem file

### Update the self signed certifcate in (identity) KeyStore with CA signed certificate & Created a new Java Key Store(Trust)  CA signed certificate(using the .pem file)

keytool -import -alias mydomain -trustcacerts -file company_cert.pem -keystore mydomain.ks

keytool -import -alias mydomain -trustcacerts -file company_cert.pem -keystore trust.jks

### On Weblogic I imported the keystores as follows and Enabled SSL.

Identity - mydomain.ks (with Private Key + CA certificate)

Trust - trust.jks (which has CA certificate)

**Issue**: Once I hit my internal site deployed on the weblogic. I  get a message - Not a trusted certificate. 
        I then download the certifcate from the browser only then https works.but the certificate shows it is signed bythe domain name I gave, instead of my Internal CA name.

**Question**: I expected it to work(with out actually downloading again) as I already have Internal CA certificates and other internal applications work on https. Did I do any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Thanks user384706.

Basically once you get a signed .pem file(with START & END) from CA.

Before you import this signed certificate to replace the self-signed in your keystore(Identity Keystore to be configured on WebLogic). We need to make sure

**1)** CA root certificates(Verisign's or your company signed CA certificates) are imported to the same Keystore. You can find CA root certs on your windows box (run-certmgr.msc).

**2)** Also make sure that all these alias names are the same -

- self-signed cert
- cert request
- while importing CA cert

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how/where you imported the certificate as you say but the browser has a different truststore than java.
So you have to add it as an exception to its truststore the first time you access the site.

As far as the domain name that is displayed the browser pops up the certificate as send by the server

Comment: CA Certificate is already present in my Trusted root. so I need not import again(I guess). I first see - Continue to this website (not recommended) and near the address it says certificate error. If I view the certificate(shows self signed, instead of CA) and import everything works fine. I don't want everyone to download the certifcicate. As I expect as CA signed cert instead.

Comment: `CA Certificate is already present in my Trusted root.` And where do you think is it?From your description it is not.In Windows it should be in `Control Panel -> Internet Options->Content (tab)->Certificates(button)` for IE to accept it as trusted

Comment: `I don't want everyone to download the certifcicate` I don't see why you concern about this.It will happen once.And it is natural to occur since it is not signed by a trusted CA (as explained in previous note)

Comment: May be I was not clear. I understand that cert(not signed by CA) needs to downloaded only once and we should be good.  The thing is every machine at work has our own Company's CA signed certificates on them, including the server machines(where we run our Integration tests). Even the cert installed on the weblogic server is company CA signed. In which case It should not prompt that Certificate is not trusted. ditto for Integ tests running servers. If it is then there is something I did wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask (again):Is the certificate under `Control Panel -> Internet Options->Content (tab)->Certificates(button)` (assumption is you use `Windows`)

Comment: Yes. I see the company signed CA certifcate there.